# Embedded Jetty and favicon

Tags: java, jetty, favicon

I am using Jetty embedded in my application as follows:

```
    ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("my.jersey.resources.package");
    ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(rc));
    ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler =
            new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    servletContextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/" + customContextPath + "/*");
    server.start();
```

Is there any way for me to add some kind of handling for a custom favicon.ico using the aforementioned setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just adding the favicon.ico to the root directory doesn't work because the browser doesn't include the app's context when fetching the favicon. Add this to your HTML:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
```

Be sure to provide a correct absolute or relative path to your favicon.

Comment: Since posting this question I solved it like you propose. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Cool. I stumbled across your question when trying to get an answer, so leaving an answer for the next guy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding favicon.ico to the root directory of where your content is located.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be off topic, but I was getting the same problem running `gradle jettyRun`. The solution was to explicitly add the `favicon.ico` file to the root of the archive.

***build.gradle***

```
war {
    from 'src/main/webapp/favicon.ico' // adds a file-set to the root of the archive
}
```